# Prove that $a$ and $b$ are relatively prime if and only if $a^2$ and $b^2$ are relatively prime.

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am stuck on this problem. I am thinking about prove it by contradiction or contrapositive. However, I could not find a way to work this out. Could someone please help me?

Comment: The fundamental theorem of arithmetic is a good place to start.

Comment: But I haven't leant that, I am sure my professor allows me to use that or not.

Comment: Then are you allowed to use Bezout's identity? (I.e. that $a$ and $b$ are coprime if and only if you can find integers $m, n$ such that $ma+nb = 1$.) It's just a consequence of the (extended) Euclidean algorithm, so you can derive it if you need to.

Comment: yes! I think that's what I supposed to use. but I have no idea how to use this to prove the question.

Answer (score 3):

$a, b$ coprime $\implies$ $a^2, b^2$ coprime:

Let $m, n$ be such that $ma + nb = 1$. Now raise this to the third power and we get
$$
m^3a^3 + 3m^2na^2b + 3mn^2ab^2 + n^3b^3 = 1\\
(m^3a + 3m^2nb)a^2 + (3mn^2a + n^3b)b^2 = 1
$$
so we have $a^2, b^2$ coprime. (I chose to raise to the third power because that forces each term to contain either $a^2$ or $b^2$ as a factor. Raising to the second power would give the awkward $2mnab$ term that I wouldn't know what to do with.)

---

$a, b$ not coprime $\implies$ $a^2, b^2$ not coprime:

Set $k = \gcd(a, b)>1$, and define $a' = \frac ak, b' = \frac bk$. Then $a', b'$ are integers, and we have
$$
a^2 = (ka')^2 = k^2a'^2\\
b^2 = (kb')^2 = k^2b'^2
$$
so $a^2$ and $b^2$ have at the very least a factor of $k^2$ in common (it turns out to be *exactly* $k^2$, but that's irrelevant) and are therefore not coprime.

Comment: Thank you so much! So I am wondering do you need to prove if a^2,b^2 coprime then a,b coprime? since its a if and only if statement.

Comment: @Xiang I did. Only I turned it around and proved "$a, b$ not coprime $\implies$ $a^2, b^2$ not coprime" instead. That's the contrapositive and it's logically equivalent (and a lot easier).

Comment: oh I see. but I am still kind of confused. What if a/k and b/k is not a integer. How did the equation shows that a^2and b^2 have at the very least a factor of k^2 in common?

Comment: @Xiang $\frac ak$ and $\frac bk$ are integers because $k$ is defined as a divisor of both $a$ and $b$. That specifically means that if you divide by it, the result it an integer. Also, since $a'^2$ is an integer, we've shown that $a^2$ has a factor of $k^2$. For the same reason $b^2$ has a factor of $k^2$. Since both $a^2$ and $b^2$ have a factor of $k^2$, that is by definition a factor they have in common.

Comment: Thank you so much! You are very helpful. Now I totally understand.

Answer (score 0):

This lemma is actually true in arbitrary GCD domains—integral domains where any two elements have a greatest common divisor. (In particular, it is true even if $\gcd(a,b)$ is *not* a linear combination of $a$ and $b$.)

Let's write $a\equiv b$ whenever $a$ and $b$ are associate and $a\mid b$ whenever $a$ divides $b$.

- First we show $c\gcd(a,b)\equiv \gcd(ac,bc)$ for any $c$. If $c$ is zero, then we are done, so suppose $c$ is nonzero. Then $d$ divides $\gcd(a,b)$ iff it divides both $a$ and $b$, iff $cd$ divides both $ac$ and $bc$, iff $cd\mid\gcd(ac,bc)$, iff $d\mid\gcd(ac,bc)/c$.
- Next we show $\gcd(a,b)\equiv 1\Rightarrow \gcd(a^2,b)\equiv 1$. Suppose $\gcd(a,b)\equiv 1$. Note that $\gcd(a^2,b)$ divides both $a^2$ and $ab$, so it divides $\gcd(a^2,ab)\equiv a\gcd(a,b)\equiv a$. Since $\gcd(a^2,b)$ divides both $a$ and $b$ , it divides $\gcd(a,b)\equiv 1$, so $\gcd(a^2,b)\equiv 1$.
- Then we show $\gcd(a,b)\equiv 1\Rightarrow \gcd(a^2,b^2)\equiv 1$. Suppose $\gcd(a,b)\equiv 1$. Then $\gcd(a^2,b)\equiv 1$ from the previous point. Let $a'=b$, $b'=(a')^2$. Then we know that $\gcd(a',b')\equiv 1$; using the previous point again gives $\gcd(a'^2,b')\equiv 1$, i.e., $\gcd(a^2,b^2)\equiv 1$.
- Finally, we show $\gcd(a^2,b^2)\equiv 1\Rightarrow \gcd(a,b)\equiv 1$. Suppose $d\mid \gcd(a,b)$. Then $d\mid a$ and $d\mid b$, so $d^2\mid a^2$ and $d^2\mid b^2$, *viz.*, $d^2\mid\gcd(a^2,b^2)$. But $\gcd(a^2,b^2)\equiv 1$, so $d^2\mid 1$, i.e., $d\equiv 1$. In particular, $\gcd(a,b)\equiv 1$.